# Can I make Safari under iPad save passwords?

Tags: ipad, safari, password

Is there a way I can make Safari on my iPad 2 save passwords or auto-fill forms.
for example, I want it to save the user/password for my wifi router so I can access it easily without typing the user/password each time I access it.

(I am using the latest firmware on an non-jailbroken iPad 2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Go to the Settings app, and select safari. There will be a section called "Autofill", and you can enable it to save your passwords and auto-fill your personal information taken from the address book. Also, iOS automatically saves all Wi-Fi passwords, so there is no need to save it manually yourself.

[image: screenshot of safari pref in ipad]

Answer (score 3):

The best alternative I found is [LoginBox](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id554782625/id554782625?mt=8). It's simpler than all of the competitors and logs into more websites, based on my tests.
The best thing about it is the ease of creating new logins and the speed of logging in afterwards. It also has a nice layout of the configured websites - a dashboard with thumbnail preview of all websites.
Bottom line, give it a try, IMHO it's much better than 1Password or LastPass and by far the best option to auto login, rather then using the form auto-fill options.

Comment: Thanks. but I'm using lastpass. it's much better. and it is a better overhaul solution across browsers, operating systems and mobile devices. I like כמה דיברתי though :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try LastPass, an online password manager -- http://lastpass.com/

The service has its own iPad browser that allows easy access to the service -- http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lastpass-tab-browser/id372722009

Comment: Downvotes should generally be commented -- what's the reason here?  This answer is on-topic and correct, even if not the best solution for the OP.  LastPass is a more robust, cross-platform solution than Mobile Safari's built-in AutoFill, and their iPad browser is just a re-packaged version of Safari with their additional feature.

Comment: it's not an answer to the question at hand. i'm just here to save test usernames/passwords to our dev device. i wasn't looking for a sales pitch.

Answer (score 1):

Another app alternative is 1Password. It works the same way as LastPass, but also has just outstanding Mac integration across Safari/Chrome/Firefox. And 1Password supports Dropbox syncing so everything stays nicely up-to-date.

[1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword/ipad)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [TapIN](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tapin-fast-auto-login-browser/id554782625?mt=8). It's an iPad app exactly for that.

I love it, saves me a lot of time every day :)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to 1Password is Wallet from Acrylic software:

http://www.acrylicapps.com/

I find the 1Password UI kind of clunky and while I've used it for a while Wallet just started offering this kind of syncing...

The idea is to attempt to use a cloud service instead of each browser's local memory to store this stuff so it syncs between devices and you're not wracking your brain for passwords on every device.

Answer (score -2):

I really prefer LoginBox which is simple

Comment: Why an answer should give an explanation rather than just a name